# Downloanding list of Image via Requests - getting TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-requests

please I have a function, that downloads a list of images and writes it to disk. Here it is:

```
def download_images(images_list, vin, make, model, year):
    images = []

    print()
    print('images list:')
    print(images_list)
    print()

    # Download all image links for a vehicle
    for iter, image_url in enumerate(images_list):
        try:
            r = requests.get(image_url, stream=True)
            r.raise_for_status()
            r.raw.decode_content = True

            filename = slugify(f"{vin} {make} {model} {year} img{iter + 1}") + '.jpg'
            filename_with_path = Path(TEMP_MEDIA_ROOT / 'original' / filename)

            with open(filename_with_path, 'wb') as f:
                shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
                images.append(filename_with_path)
            logging.info('(1) download: ' + filename)

        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError:
            logging.exception('download_images - HTTPError')
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
            logging.exception('download_images - ConnectionError')
        except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
            logging.exception('download_images - Timeout')
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
            logging.exception('download_images - RequestException')

    return images
```

It works well. But this function downloads a lot of images from a server. And I don't know if the remote server terminates the connection, or it is a function issue. So after some time, when this function downloads a lot of images, it ends this way:

```
images list:
['http://example.com/image1.JPG', 'http://example.com/image2.JPG', 'http://example.com/image3.JPG'
['http://example.com/image4.JPG', 'http://example.com/image5.JPG', 'http://example.com/image6.JPG'
['http://example.com/image7.JPG', 'http://example.com/image8.JPG', 'http://example.com/image9.JPG'
'http://example.com/image10.JPG',]

2021-01-12 08:48:10,979 [INFO]: (1) download: examplevin-examplemake-examplemodel-2021-img1.jpg               
2021-01-12 08:48:11,177 [INFO]: (1) download: examplevin-examplemake-examplemodel-2021-img2.jpg               
2021-01-12 08:48:11,391 [INFO]: (1) download: examplevin-examplemake-examplemodel-2021-img3.jpg               
2021-01-12 08:48:11,598 [INFO]: (1) download: examplevin-examplemake-examplemodel-2021-img4.jpg               
2021-01-12 08:48:11,747 [INFO]: (1) download: examplevin-examplemake-examplemodel-2021-img5.jpg               
2021-01-12 08:48:11,869 [INFO]: (1) download: examplevin-examplemake-examplemodel-2021-img6.jpg               
2021-01-12 08:48:12,070 [INFO]: (1) download: examplevin-examplemake-examplemodel-2021-img7.jpg               
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback:                
"""                                                  
Traceback (most recent call last):                   
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 125, in worker                                  
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))             
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 48, in mapstar                                  
    return list(map(*args))                          
  File "..../myscript.py", line 567, in process_vehicle                                                                                                             
    down_images = download_images(original_images, vin, make_name, model_name, year)                      
  File "..../myscript.py", line 437, in download_images                                                                                                             
    for iter, image_url in enumerate(images_list):                                                        
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable         
"""                                                  

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:                                      

Traceback (most recent call last):                   
  ...
  ...
  ...
  File "..../myscript.py", line 623, in handle                                                                                                                      
    main()                                           
  File "..../myscript.py", line 613, in main              
    parallelize_dataframe(df, process_vehicle)                                                            
  File "..../myscript.py", line 601, in parallelize_dataframe                                                                                                       
    pool.map(func, df_split)                         
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 364, in map                                     
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()                                      
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 771, in get                                     
    raise self._value                                
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

So, there are 10 images in the list and it successfully downloads 7 of them, but the rest of the images were not downloaded.

When I check directory, where images should be saved, there is also 8th image, but its size in kB is lower, than others:

```
myuser@server:~/$ ls -l --block-size=KB
total 3777kB
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myuser myuser 646kB Jan 12 08:48 examplevin-examplemake-examplemodel-2021-img1.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myuser myuser 364kB Jan 12 08:48 examplevin-examplemake-examplemodel-2021-img2.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myuser myuser 465kB Jan 12 08:48 examplevin-examplemake-examplemodel-2021-img3.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myuser myuser 522kB Jan 12 08:48 examplevin-examplemake-examplemodel-2021-img4.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myuser myuser 340kB Jan 12 08:48 examplevin-examplemake-examplemodel-2021-img5.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myuser myuser 227kB Jan 12 08:48 examplevin-examplemake-examplemodel-2021-img6.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myuser myuser 570kB Jan 12 08:48 examplevin-examplemake-examplemodel-2021-img7.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myuser myuser  66kB Jan 12 08:48 examplevin-examplemake-examplemodel-2021-img8.jpg
```

So it looks like, there is some issue with the connection - the image was not downloaded correctly. But I am not 100% sure. Is there any way, how treat this behavior in the Requests library, please?

Or there is an issue in my for loop? I am going try to change this loop in this way:

```
for count, item in enumerate(items, start=1):
```

And I will also try this "low-level" variant:

```
index = 0
for item in items:
    print(index, item)
    index += 1
```

I will be glad for any advice. Thank you!

**EDIT - CLOSED:**
As I have commented: When I printed out the image_url variable, I have found, that it must be a server error - because sometimes the file does not exist on the server. And I have also renamed iter to index.

Thank you @pistolpete

Comment: This looks like an issue with your for loop. If you comment all of the code in the for loop and just print out the image_url variable for each iteration does it work?

Comment: Shadowing the iter keyword is also making things confusing here and I would suggest renaming that variable

Comment: When I printed out the image_url variable, I have found, that it must be a server error - because sometimes the file does not exist on the server. And I have also renamed iter to index. Thank you.

Comment: Happy to help! Glad you figured it out